# treetable checkbox issue SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sapui5, treetable

got a bug with treetable and checkboxes on SAPUI5, with expanded tree item, the selected checkboxes of each items are moving with scrollbar :) hope i was clear, is there any way to solve this bug?!
thank you all for help!

i think there can be the problem with model and dom disconnection... but im not sure

**Before:**

[image]

**After i scroll:**

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example (for example as Plunker)?

Comment: @hirse unfortunately no, i cant because i cant simulate it, the sapui5 version is 1.28, quite old, i can describe the problem is like that row index seems for treetable doesnt change, it counts the visible rows, but not the model's one, thus the checked checkbox seems always checked on the same row...because the visible row index doesnt change while scrolling, but the model's row index changes...

Comment: 1.28 is still available publicly: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.32/resources/sap-ui-core.js

Comment: at least add an screenshot ...

Comment: @hirse it is very hard to copy the code, coz pc has no internet connection and the tables uses xsodata from lan connected server's database, but i added 2 screenshots, hope it will help.

Comment: @zyrex i added screenshots, as u can see the checked boxes are moving along with scroller :)

Comment: Pretty strange... the data binding should keep the value for the check boxes in place, regardless of the state of the expanded/collapsed tree row and/or position